# Testing message headers in nServicebus

Tags: unit-testing, nservicebus

I'm struggling to get message headers to work from my unit tests in nServiceBus (v3.3.0.0). The headers get set in the test using SetIncomingHeader(...), but when I call GetHeader(...) in the message handler, I get the string:

> No header get header action was defined, please spicify one using
>   ExtensionMethods.GetHeaderAction = ...

The headers work fine outside of the testing framework.

The FullDuplex sample app basically shows the code I'm using and suffers the same problem. Does anyone know how I set up the GetHeaderAction method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, can you raise an issue in [github](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/new)

Comment: I've created an issue, see https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/933

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in [Why NServiceBus OutgoingHeaders is static and not ThreadStatic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411371/why-nservicebus-outgoingheaders-is-static-and-not-threadstatic), you can define your own GetHeaderAction, which is called when unit testing your project, when NSB is obviously not running.

```
ExtensionMethods.GetHeaderAction =
    ((msg, key) => this.Manager.GetHeader(msg, key));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John, this is fixed in

- https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/933

Also, make sure that you are using the NServiceBus.Testing framework as documented here:

- http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/testing/

Example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Run()
    {
        Test.Initialize();

        Test.Handler<MyMessageHandler>()
            .SetIncomingHeader("Test", "abc")
            .ExpectReply<ResponseMessage>(m => Test.Bus.GetMessageHeader(m, "MyHeaderKey") == "myHeaderValue")
            .OnMessage<RequestMessage>(m => m.String = "hello");
    }
}

class MyMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<RequestMessage>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(RequestMessage message)
    {
        ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage();
        Bus.SetMessageHeader(responseMessage, "MyHeaderKey", "myHeaderValue");
        Bus.Reply(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Please note, this is for NServiceBus v4/v5. For other versions visit the documentation.